# How to read what is actually inside a ListView and not the position it is in on android app?

Tags: android, listview

I have an ListView which I have populate with a dynamic ArrayList and I used an OnItemClickListener to make it does something when i click on them (Code bellow).

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,txtOnlyList);
returnSaveNotesList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener noteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> txtOnlyList, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position == 0 ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReadFromFile1.this, SaveAndRstoreNote.class);
            intent.putExtra("firstNote","1 .txt");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
returnSaveNotesList.setOnItemClickListener(noteClickListener);
```

Now comes the tricky part, I want, somehow to be able to read what is actually written lets say on the position [0], the actual String. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: means you want to get your selected index string on Listview.setOnItemClick event right?

Comment: Yes something like that..!

Comment: if you satisfy with answer accept it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> txtOnlyList, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position == 0) {
        String yourString = txtOnlyList.get(position);// use this                             
        Intent intent = new Intent(ReadFromFile1.this, SaveAndRstoreNote.class);
        intent.putExtra("firstNote", "1 .txt");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason .get(position) wasn't recognized.

Comment: if your Arraylist having that much of items, what index you passing it will work, its not working means , there is problem with your code.

Comment: I am fairly new to android so there is a big chance that i have done something wrong. However my code compile and run as it should by using  'getItemAtPosition' ..!

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArrayAdapter<String>` has a `getItem()` method that returns the `String` for a given `position`.

Comment: Wow, that was quick..!! I will try it and return with the results..!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The View type parameter being passed in your OnItemClick function is the list item's view at that position.

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener noteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> txtOnlyList, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        String text = tv.getText().toString(); //The required text is available in this variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `getItemAtPosition(position)`.

Here is the entire code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,txtOnlyList);
returnSaveNotesList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener noteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> txtOnlyList, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position == 0 ){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReadFromFile1.this, SaveAndRstoreNote.class);
            String stringFromArray=txtOnlyList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); // I added this
            intent.putExtra("firstNote","1 .txt");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
returnSaveNotesList.setOnItemClickListener(noteClickListener);
```